# Issue with expo-image-picker rotating camera images by 90 degrees on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Has anyone faced similar issues where the camera image gets rotated by 90 degrees after being captured using expo-image-picker package ?

***Below is my code***

````
    let result = await launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    })

    console.log(result)

    if (result.cancelled === false) {
      setCurrentImage(result)
    }
  }

  const takePicture = async () => {
    const result = await launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: false,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    })

    console.log(result)
    if (result.cancelled === false) {
      setCurrentImage(result)
    }
  }```
````

Comment: What are you doing in setCurrentImage(result)? It looks you are not using rotation information.

Comment: yes I am not using rotation image because the end user never rotates the image. On IOS, I don't have to rotate anything, it keeps it's original orientation

Comment: `yes I am not using rotation image because the end user never rotates the image. ` Your answer makes no sense. You are complaining that your bitmap is rotated. So use the rotation information to make the bitmap unrotated.

Comment: @blackapps so result doesn't have the rotation information. the object of the result only has uri, height, width, cancelled

Answer (score 0):

You can check the response that you get after take the picture and if the rotation is 90 you can use react-native-image-resizer to change it, maybe you only have this problem on Android or ios too?

Comment: I only have this problem on android but I tried using expo-image-manipulator but I get this error saying - `[the method or property ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync is not available on android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]`

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved by rebuilding my app after I install ImageManipulator